# How can I intercept a JSON response of a POST request in a WebView?

Tags: android, json, post, webview, response

I'm currently developing a login module. After click the "login" button in a WebView, the browser will receive a json response, and then redirect to the another page. How can I intercept this json response?

I tried `shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url)` and print all the url input, but I can not find the json response.

```
mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest (final WebView view, String url) {
            Log.i("InterceptRequest", url);
            return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            Log.i("onPageStarted", url);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.i("onPageFinished", url);
        }

    });
```

I also noticed that when I can not see this response in Chrome and Firefox, but I can see it in IE.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Override shouldOverrideUrlLoading on the webclient :

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url) {

    URL aURL = new URL(url); 
            URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection(); 
            conn.connect(); 
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream(); 
            // read inputstream to get the json..
            ...
            ...
            return true;
}
```

Comment: ignore the flag is from a non-related code :P, try again with the edited code

Comment: But this url is the main page that has been redirected to after login:(

Comment: I don't know if this was valid at the time of writing but it is not anymore.
The documentation explicitly states "Note: This method is not called for POST requests."

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest)

Comment: This doesn't solution to catch json response. This is catch url and manual to excute other request to server.